# Select different objects and sort them using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have different tables, and different data, but they all share a common `Created` DateTime column.

Is it possible in LINQ to do a `select` query on all the 4 tables and sort all the objects by `Created`
and return them as a List?

Comment: you mean Linq To Entities ? Linq To Sql ? Linq to ObjecT ?

Comment: Well, simple join would do the job i guess, i dont see the problem here.

Comment: @Botis, How join will work, inner join ruled out as  no maching column. Cross join will create undesirable no. of records. Full outer join might do the trick, but is it efficient enough?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
t1.Select(i => new {Value = (object)i, Created = i.Created})
  .Concat(t2.Select(i => new {Value = (object)i, Created = i.Created}))
  .Concat(t3.Select(i => new {Value = (object)i, Created = i.Created}))
  .Concat(t4.Select(i => new {Value = (object)i, Created = i.Created}))
  .OrderBy(i => i.Created)
  .Select(i => i.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) might be more efficient if duplicates are allowed. http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2009/03/04/choose-concat-over-union-if-possible.aspx

Comment: It isn't may be, it must be concat! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could query your tables with

```
var q1 = from t1 select Created;
var q2 = from t2 select Created;
var q3 = from t3 select Created;
var q4 = from t4 select Created;
```

and then use

```
var res = q1.Union(q2).Union(q3).Union(q4).OrderBy(p=>p).ToList();
```

or

```
var q1 = (from t1 select Created)
         .Union(from t2 select Created)
         .Union(from t3 select Created)
         .Union(from t4 select Created)
         .OrderBy(p=>p).ToList();
```

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I forgot it :)

Comment: Had you selected the Created field values and have tried to sort collection by the field?

Comment: Result of your cade is the List<DateTime>, isn't it?

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh: my edited answer should work now. Thanks for your suggestion :)